# can't Explore Data in a Jupyter Notebook using python 3 azure machine learning studio

Tags: python

Can anybody help me please? I am new to machine learning Studio.
I am using free azure machine learning studio workspace 
trying to use in cell run all got the following error.

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-17afe06b8f16> in <module>()
      1 from azureml import Workspace
      2 
----> 3 ws = Workspace()
      4 ds = ws.datasets['Lemonadecsv.csv']
home/nbuser/anaconda3_23/lib/python3.4/site-packages/azureml/__init__.py in __init__(self, workspace_id, authorization_token, endpoint)
    883         endpoint = https://studio.azureml.net
    884         """
--> 885         workspace_id, authorization_token, endpoint, management_endpoint = _get_workspace_info(workspace_id, authorization_token, endpoint, None)
    886 
    887         _not_none_or_empty('workspace_id', workspace_id)

/home/nbuser/anaconda3_23/lib/python3.4/site-packages/azureml/__init__.py in _get_workspace_info(workspace_id, authorization_token, endpoint, management_endpoint)
    849 
    850         if workspace_id is None:
--> 851             raise ValueError('workspace_id not provided and not available via config')
    852         if authorization_token is None:
    853             raise ValueError('authorization_token not provided and not available via config')

ValueError: workspace_id not provided and not available via config
      5 frame = ds.to_dataframe()
```

Answer (score 3):

I have same problem as you. I have contacted tech support so once I get an answer, I will update this post. Meanwhile, you can use this **WORKAROUND**:

Get missing parameters and input them as Strings.

```
ws = Workspace("[WORKSPACE_ID]", "[AUTH_TOKEN]")
```

Where to get them: 
[WOKRSPACE_ID]: Azure ML Studio -> Settings -> Name Tab -> WorkspaceId
[AUTH_TOKEN]: Azure ML Studio -> Settings -> Authorization Token Tab -> Primary AUTH Token.

Comment: OK appreciate !!

Answer (score 2):

You can also go to Dataset-> Check/highlight the dataset you are working on -> Generate Data Access Code (down below).

Copy and paste the generated code into the first cell in your python notebook. It should look similar to this.

```
from azureml import Workspace
ws = Workspace(
    workspace_id='WORKSPACEID',
    authorization_token='AUTH_TOKEN',
    endpoint='https://studioapi.azureml.net'
)
ds = ws.datasets['Lemonade.csv']
frame = ds.to_dataframe()
```

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way is to right click on the data set you have and choose Generate Data Access Code, the system will do it for you and all you have to do is to copy it to the frame and it all will be there.

I hope this helps!